# Variable in a name

Tags: java, android-fragments, operators, simple-framework

```
final ImageView element = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.element);
final ImageView name = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.name);
Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        element.setImageResource(image_elements[1]);
        name.setImageResource(image_names[1]);
    }
});
```

My code works when hard coded but I want to use operators like `++` and `--`. Why can't I? Example below.

```
element.setImageResource(image_elements[++]);
name.setImageResource(image_names[++]);
```

Why doesn't this work and how can I get it to.

Comment: What are you expecting `image_elements[++]` and `image_names[++]` to do?

Comment: Operator does an operation with an operand. Minimal number of operands is one (*unary operator*), e.g. `!a`, `a++`. *Binary operator* has two operands, e.g. `a + b`, `a & b`. *Ternary operator* has three operands, e.g. `a ? b : c`. Operator without the operand doesn't make a sense. What it should do according to you?

Comment: Why not simply use a field for your index variable and then increment after you use it within your inner anonymous class?

Comment: BTW it's not about programming at all, it's elementary school mathematics. What's the result of `1 + 1`? And what's the result of `+`, or `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to move to the next element on each click, why not simply use an int index field and increment it?

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    private int i = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // parallel array anti-pattern below is a no-no
        element.setImageResource(image_elements[i]);
        name.setImageResource(image_names[i]);
        i++;

        // if you want to cycle elements of the array and 
        // to prevent array index out of bounds:
        i %= image_elements.length;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I simply did not think of such a simple solution. OMG thank you so much.

Comment: When i try it on the "previous button" iteration of the code it doesn't work. It  jumps to 1, then 0 then crashes. The only change is "i++;" to "i--;". Thoughts on why that doesn't work?

Comment: Come on, a negative index doesn't make sense. You're asking questions that are extremely basic and suggest that you might want to study from a Java book or two.